# How to create solution with multiple projects programmatically?

Tags: c#, envdte, microsoft.build

I want to create solution with multiple projects.

I think I have three options:

1. [EnvDTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
2. [Microsoft.Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145008.aspx)
3. Manually create *.sln and *.csproj files

I googled but didn't found good examples for 1 and 2 options (*I mean how to create solution, add projects, add refereces, add new or existing project items, etc...*)

third option, I think, is easier but if there are good options, I don't need to create projects manually.

#### So my questions are:

*Is there any other options to create projects programmatically?*

and *Which option is better?*

Thanks.

Comment: MSBuild is for compiling solutions, not for creating the actual solution files. Since build typically is a synonym for compile, please edit your post and replace "build" with "create" where appropriate to make it less confusing to read.

Comment: What's your purpose?  Also, templates are a fourth way.  T4 is a fifth.

Comment: @Will When I use WCF, I always create WCF service and client manually. But it's a tedious task. So I'm trying to automate this process (Adding Services, contracts, Service functions and client code generation) http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0809101&page=1

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze: I'd suggest a template, and add some T4 templates to generate the boilerplate client code based on the service contract.

Comment: @Will I'll try T4 templates. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I haven't tried it but check this out: https://github.com/chucknorris/warmup/wiki

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample ?

Comment: @Vano Maisuradze...did you ever find a solution for this? I am trying to accomplish the exact same thing and the research is painful.

Answer (score 2):

Just manually create the sln and csproj files (and other required files) manually, the formats are very simple. You can make this an easy task by creating a new solution with two projects in Visual Studio, and just inspecting the contents of the sln and csproj files. The idea here is that you are just making yourself a template.